# Magento 2.3 stock (salable quantity) is not updated quickly once order has placed

Tags: magento2.3

I'm working on Magento 2.3 EE.

Currently, I have displayed the salable quantity in frontend. ( It's showing the correct value that was available in the admin product grid.)

If I have placed any order means, automatically the salable quantity to be decreased. Because I have set the value of **Decrease Stock When Order is Placed** is set to **Yes**.

But the problem was if I have placed an order, the salable quantity to be reduced only the cache has been flushed. Not get reduced the quantity once the order has been placed with cache flush.

Is there any solution to avoid the quantity update without a deal with cache flush and permission.

Please give some suggestion to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be clarify, Salable qty decreased only when you flush cache after placing an order ?

Comment: Yes. I have tried 10 times by placing the order. At every time it reflects after flushed the cache.

Comment: This is weird, I'm using MSI and I haven't faced this issue, I can give you one workaround to resolve this issue, You can observe checkout success  and flush cache programmatically.